# Log4net Logging to AppInsight as Trace

Tags: c#, azure, log4net, azure-application-insights, log4net-appender

Currently I am using Log4net Appender for App Insight, to log the error to Application Insight.

```
 TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "XXXX";

            var tc = new TelemetryClient();
            var log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            log.Error(ex+ "@"+ CodeBlock); **IN this case its loggin as Trace.**             log.Fatal(ex + "@" + CodeBlock);
            log.Info(ex + "@" + CodeBlock);

            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel.DeveloperMode = true;
            tc.Flush();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

In this case, all of the events are logged as Trace. But where I expect it logged as exception. I can use telemetry object to pass the exception but then there won't be any result of using of Log4net. We can't pass the log entry to any other logging tools except App insight.

Comment: have you solved the issue as per answer below?

Comment: yes its working now , as it was bit delayed but it was always working.

Comment: if it works, can you help mark it as an answer? it would help others.

Answer (score 1):

For logged as exception, you should use this line of code `log.Error("your message",new Exception());`

In visual studio output window, if you use `log.Error("your message",new Exception());`, you can see the `Application Insights Telemetry` has a name ends with `Exception`, like below:
[image]

Then go to azure portal, you can see the it goes as Exception, screenshot below:
[image]